# Garbage Collection in Linked list

Tags: garbage-collection

I have a class `LinkedList`.

```
class LinkedList {
  int info;
  LinkedList next;
}
```

I have a variable `list` pointing to a linked list with 3 elements.
`list`: `root->element1->element2->null`

I want this list to be garbage collected now.
Will making root as `null` solve the problem?

Comment: you're supposed to accept one of the answers; or at least comment why you don't like them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be yes...

- assuming it's a garbage collected language (such as Java or C#, deciding by the syntax)
- and assuming nothing else is pointing to `element1`

Furthermore, if something points to just `element2`, `element1` will be collected but `element2` won't.

If you set `list` to `null`, the entire list becomes candidate to be GC-d. If you set the next element of `root` to `null`, the tail (i.e. all but the head or first element) will become candidate to be GC-d.

Comment: Will this be achieved in a single pass of garbage collection or multiple passes will be required?

Comment: I think that depends on the GC implementation, but I guess multiple passes in case of a simple implementation. Somebody more competent could shed some light on this though.

Comment: Hello @Erik. Can you kindly point me how I can manually test this?

Comment: @AzuxirentLeadGuy I’m afraid you’d have to ask this in a separate question. It would involve some kind of GC level debugging/tracing.

Answer (score 1):

yes , objects eligible for garbage collector are those without any identifiers  referencing to them